# Progression with Bluebird in a safe code block

Tags: promise, bluebird

I want to create a code block within Bluebird that is safe and has access to progress() - is this possible:

One way of doing what I want is with exception handlers - but I'm looking for a solution without:

```
var deferred = Promise.defer();
try {
    ...
    deferred.progress(10);
    ...
} catch(e) {
    deferred.reject(e);
} 
return deferred.promise;
```

Also according to the documentation:

> The use of Promise.defer is discouraged - it is much more awkward and error-prone than using new Promise.

So I can do this:

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    ...
});
```

But I have no way of progressing that one?

Thanks,

Comment: You want an event emitter, not a promise

Comment: No, I want a promise :)

Comment: What do you mean by "safe"?

Comment: Sorry, by safe I just mean that all exceptions should be caught by Bluebird

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Promise.method` can be used to make any function safe

```
var fn = Promise.method(function() {

    var deferred = Promise.defer();
    deferred.progress(10);
    return deferred.promise;

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You're right, the `new Promise` constructor does not provide a way to fire progress events. The reason is probably the ongoing discussion about the [promise construction spec](https://github.com/promises-aplus/constructor-spec), where none of the proposed methods has been approved yet.

You can check what the [PromiseResolver `.progress()` method](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/a5a5d0772379894294e71021c6233ad7a5dfb6c0/src/promise_resolver.js#L128) does: you just would need to call the "private", undocumented `._progress()` method on the promise - but that is not advisable.

Answer (score 0):

@Esailija

Thanks, almost what I ended up with ....

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var deferred = Promise.defer();
    ....
    deferred.progress(10);
    ....
    resolve(deferred.promise);
});
```